# Flutter build and show webpage

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I would like to create a webpage using Flutter.
Both the commands

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

and

```
flutter build web
```

work without an error and the build - folder is created.

I don't understand - however - how I can now use the content of the build folder. When I open the `index.html` file in my browser, I get an empty webpage. Do I have to perform another step before I can see the build webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run 'web server'
Refer to https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web#deploying-to-the-web

Answer (score 1):

After changing to channel beta by running:

```
$ flutter channel beta
$ flutter upgrade
$ flutter config --enable-web
```

You need to make sure your project has web support. You can do:

```
$ flutter create .
```

To add support to existing project. Also the build command should not be neccessary unless you want to create a release build in most cases. Just using:

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

Should be fine as long as you have chrome installed. Since the page is blank, wait a little a little while since the contents dont appear till the engine is loaded. Also check if %project_dir%/lib/main.dart is empty (which it should not be if you created a new project).